# CodeDeploy fails "stop: command not found"

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to deploy a React Application via CodePipeline; my 3 steps are

- Github source (passes)
- CodeBuild (passes)
- CodeDeploy (fails)

Buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - npm install
      - npm install -g webpack-cli
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Compiling
      - webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --env BACKEND_URL=$BACKEND_URL
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
    - build/**/*
    - public/**/*
    - dist/**/*
    - src/**/*
    - config/**/*
    - scripts/**/*
    - package.json
    - appspec.yml
```

Appspec.yml

```
version: 0.0
os: linux

files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ec2-user/server

permissions:
  - object: /
    pattern: "**"
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user

hooks:

  ApplicationStop:
    - location: scripts/app_stop.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root

  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/before_install.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root

  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/app_start.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
```

app_stop.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo systemctl stop nginx
```

before_install.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ec2-user/server
amazon-linux-extras install nginx1
```

app_start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ec2-user/server
cp build/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
cp -R dist /var/www/html/taxi-booker
nginx
```

CodeDeploy is currently failing with this log in the "ApplicationStop" step. The first time I ran this pipeline it passed fine (without ApplicationStop) however if I run it without this step, the nginx port is already in use.

```
LifecycleEvent - ApplicationStop
Script - scripts/app_stop.sh
[stderr]/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/9ce189ed-1f48-4cdb-b01f-e7cd8986c8b7/d-QUYBUBMKC/deployment-archive/scripts/app_stop.sh: line 2: stop: command not found
```

Any idea what the proper way to deploy with nginx is? Thanks a lot

Logs:[image]

Comment: The docs here talk about how ApplicationStop doesn't run the first time, so it makes sense it could pass the first run then fail the second: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your application stop hook with :

```
#!/bin/bash
service nginx stop
```

complement :

Try to execute the command to stop nginx inside your instance EC2, not from CodeDeploy, like a root / ec2-user maybe its permissions Idk, but try to fix the status of nginx from the command, once you fix it, you can re-run the CodeDeploy job, the error is not from CodeDeploy but with the command.

You see that 127 code, that means command not found. Fix it first in your terminal inside your EC2, then rerun the CodeDeploy job

Comment: I gave this a try and received the same error

Comment: Could you share the logs of codedeploy in your instance like 
less /var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log

Comment: Updated answer with logs

Comment: try to execute the command to stop nginx inside your instance EC2, not from CodeDeploy, like a root / ec2-user  maybe its permissions Idk, but try to fix the status of nginx from the command, once you fix it, you can re-run the CodeDeploy job

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I managed to run "systemctl stop nginx" on my EC2 no problem, as well as start, status etc. But when trying that command in the deploy pipeline as above, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Both as root as well

Comment: Just for testing purposes, try to remove the permissions(ec2-user...) part from appspec. and rerun the job

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240019/discussion-between-hatim-and-daniel-m).